# Regex detect if a matched comma(,) does not lie in a regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out a way to determine if my matched comma(,) does not lie inside a regex. Basically, i do not want to match my character if it lies in a regex.

The regex i have come up with is `,(?<!.+\/)(?!.+\/)` but its not quite working.
Any ideas?

I want to skip `/some,regex/` but match any other commas.

**Edit:**
Live example: http://rubular.com/r/WjrwSnmzyP

Comment: Can you provide a sample list of patterns that __should__ and __should not__ match? I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: What texts do you search in? And what regex tool are you using for that?

Comment: The only way to do it in regex is to check that the comma is followed by an even number of slashes until the document end.

Comment: The concept of a regex is not defined when given a bunch of text. You seem to want to find something that is not between 2 `/`'s. And this is sort of difficult to do with regex, since you have to keep track of all `/`'s thus far or count all of those 'til the end to determine whether the first `/` you find was a start or finish (unless there can only be 2 `/`'s in all the text. So, basically, regex is most likely not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Bergi That is not only not the *only* way, it is the *wrong* way.

Comment: @PointedEars: It's afaik the only way to *match exactly* those. Of course the solution from your answer is preferable, parsing out the to-be-ignored expressions and handle them different when matched.

Comment: There are many different flavours of regular expressions. You should say which programming language or tool you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex that will work for you:

```
,(?!\s)(?=(?:(?:[^/]*\/){2})*[^/]*$)
```

#### Live Demo: http://rubular.com/r/37buDdg1tW

**Explanation:** It means match comma followed by EVEN number of forward slash `/`. Hence `comma (,)` between 2 `slash (/)` characters will NOT be matched and outside ones will be matched (since those are followed by even number of `/` characters).

Comment: What about slashes in regular expressions?  What about slashes in string literals, or as division operators?

Comment: In the absence of a specified programming language / regex tool its difficult to come up with a alternate solution.

Comment: @PratikKhadloya: You can see all your examples here: http://rubular.com/r/OsErJO0IhL with my regex above.

Comment: As you can see, it is not that difficult.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, but the regex should not match commas which already have a space after it. Combining your regex and mine seems to do the job. Demo here: http://rubular.com/r/x3MFII0agA . But can we shorten it somehow?

Comment: @PratikKhadloya: It definitely can be shortened, see this demo now: http://rubular.com/r/37buDdg1tW

Comment: @PratikKhadloya You have still not said which regular expression flavour you are talking about. For example, Rubular is a “*Ruby* regular expression editor”. Are you looking for a *Ruby* RE?

Answer (score 0):

A curious thing about regular expressions is that if you want to use them to *ignore* "something" that is *within* "something else", you need to *match* that "something else", *prefer matches* of it, and then either *silently discard* or *reproduce* those matches.

For example, in order to remove all commas from a string *unless* they are in a regular expression literal—

In Perl:

```
my $s = "/foo,bar/,baz";
$s =~ s{(/(?:[^/\\]|\\.)+/)|,}{\1}g;
```

In ECMAScript:

```
var s = "/foo,bar/,baz";
s = s.replace(/(\/([^\/\\]|\\.)+\/)|,/g, "$1");
```

or

```
s = s.replace(new RegExp("(/([^/\\\\]|\\\\.)+/)|,", "g"), "$1");
```

Note that I am *capturing* the match for the regular expression literal in the string value, and *reproducing* it (`\1` or `$1`) if it matched. (If the other part of the alternation – the standalone comma – matched, the empty string is captured, so this simple approach suffices *here*.)

For further reading I recommend [“Mastering Regular Expressions”](http://regex.info/) by Jeffrey E. F. Friedl.  Two rather enlightening example chapters, each from a different edition, are available for free online.

Comment: OP did not ask about Java/EcmaScript - and since he's using lookbehind, that is even very unlikely.

Comment: (_JavaScript_ and _ECMAScript_, please.) This approach works for any programming language where the first match in an alternation wins. In particular, it works also for [Perl Regular Expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions](http://pcre.org/), which is about as definitive as you can get with this problem description.

Comment: @PointedEars: Read the question again: **Regex detect if a matched comma(,) does not lie in a regex** OP isn't asking you to replace anything. Use your regex to do a `match` on this string: `"/foo,bar/,baz,dt=1/1/2013"` and see what happens.

Comment: I am fully aware that replacing was not asked. However, replacing is an *easy* way to do a global match and decide what do to with the match each time (especially if the programming language allows you to use a callback for the replacement value). BTDT. What would happen with *matching* the expression against your string is that the matches are, in order, `/foo,bar/`, `,`, `,`, and `/1/`. You can then decide, for example in a loop, to ignore `/foo,bar/` and `/1/`.  `/\//` will also be properly matched. I hope you understand my approach now and revert the downvote.

Comment: @PointedEars: I wanted to revert my downvote and SO didn't allow me therefore I had to perform a dummy edit of your answer.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you. Also for the revert solution – I will remember that :)